# Object distorting in edit mode

Tags: edit-mode, sculpting, retopology, multiresolution

I sculpted an object using a multiresolution modifier in sculpt mode, and now I want to try my hand at retopology. The issue is when I go to edit mode, the object looks nothing like what I created in sculpt mode. It looks fine in sculpt and object mode. Anyone know how I can fix this, or do I have to start from scratch and try to do it without multiresolution?

[image: Image in sculpt mode]

[image: Image in edit mode]

Comment: Maybe duplicate your object and apply the Mutlires modifier on the copy? Also you're talking about retopology, but you need to create a brand new mesh to retopologize, unless you want a remesher instead of doing it manually but it won't give the best result

Answer (score 1):

The Multires Modifier does not deform the original, low-poly mesh. Imagine baking a cake, then applying the icing - the Multires sculpts only that icing on top of the cake. To keep and apply your sculpted Multires details first make sure your Preview, Sculpt, and Render values are the same, then in Object Mode apply the modifier. This should allow your object to reflect all the current changes.